# Django image not storing

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-views

I am trying to upload the image of desktop to the server using ModelView. It's storing link into the database but image is not getting uploaded into the MEDIA folder.

Models:

```
class File(models.Model):
#       file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
        file = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True)
        remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

URL:
path('upload/', views.FileView.as_view(), name='file-upload'),

Serializer:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields="__all__"
```

View:

```
class FileView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

Global settings:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Output:

```
"id": 18,
    "file": "https://<URL>/media/home/tguser/tgportal/core/media/check.png",
    "remark": "ok",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-19T16:43:50.131435Z"
}
```

The file link is generating but no file uploded at that location.

Any help appreciated.

PD

Comment: have you created a media directory yet and defined the static root/url?

Comment: Yes, MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/media')

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: that's good   then. Try to remove the `blank=True` from file field, it automatically allows the file to be submitted as null. make sure to run migrations again afterward. also, what logic are you performing to store the image? usually I use Django's built-in [FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/storage/), and [the tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) I used.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed blank=true. The link is getting stored but not actual image. I follwed that tutorial aleady. I will check your other link though.This is my view code to store the file:
class FileView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

Comment: Problem is solved. My media folder path was wrong. After corrrection its working now.